# find combobox that have selections

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How can I loop through a group of combo boxes in a wpf form and find the ones that have selected values? All the combo boxes are in a grid container called BoxContainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
foreach (var comboBox in BoxContainer.Children.OfType<ComboBox>())
    if (comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox.Name);
```

Comment: Please I have another question; I'm using a listview to display the combo boxes' selections which are saved in a collection at every comboboxes selection. My question is when I loop through the combo boxes, how can I populate a list < comboitems> = new list <comboitem>() with the selected items